# BinaryFormatter Endiannes

Tags: c#, endianness, binaryformatter

We use BinaryFormatter to serialize objects into a NetworkStream and transfer them through TCP Sockets.

I was just trying to figure out if the Endiannes is fixed or if is system dependent.

I know that BinaryWriter uses always LittleEndian, I was trying to find the same type of information for BinaryFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

BinaryFormatter uses the internal __BinaryParser class to take care of decoding bytes.  Look at its [ReadInt16() method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/serialization/formatters/binary/binaryparser.cs,3079e947a95e3438) as one that has an endian dependency.  Click on "dataReader" to see that it is simply a BinaryReader that gets that job done.

BinaryReader always uses little-endian, regardless of the system default.

Same story for __BinaryWriter.WriteInt16(), the internal method that BinaryFormatter uses to write an Int16, uses BinaryWriter.  Do note that you'll never actually test this, the only non-trivial big-endian host that can execute C# code is the olden XBox 360.  Which does not support System.Net

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with two applications use the `BinaryReader/BinaryWriter`, not the `BinaryFormatter. BinaryFormatter` is not a good for serializing data across a wire, it was designed mainly for IPC in mind. if you pass data onto another system its not a good idea.
Read here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx. 
Also here: http://ambracode.com/index/show/244765